# How does register the file extension in vdproj,so that it will automatically open in the concern application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, vdproj

I need to register the file extension in vdproj,so that when setup is installed by someone the file is opens into registered extension.

Say for example if my program exe is able to read text file with extension of `.tet`, so when i create any text file with extension `.tet` like sample.tet ,it should be open into my program exe not `notepad`.

Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: There are dozens of previous posts here about how to associate a specific file extension with your application. All of those would apply to a setup as well. Have you searched here? Try `register file extension`, which turned up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720710/register-file-extension-in-window-registry) as the second result.

Comment: The short answer is that you go View=>Editor=>File Types, and then right click File Types on Target Machine and add file type, fill in the properties.