# Creating File Extensions for my application

Tags: c#, file-extension, file-association

I'm wondering how I can create my own file extension to work with my application. For example, say I wanted to have a ".abc" extension. The full file name example would be "MyFile.abc".
I want the file to behave in a way that when it is double clicked, it will open up in my application, but actually it contains data of a .xml file.

Sorry if this makes little sense, this is completely new to me. I'm using c# in visual studio 2013, and basically my application is an automatic update installer. I want it so when my file with my own extension is selected, my application opens and uses the xml data from it to do the update.

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376631/How-to-make-your-own-file-type-for-your-Csharp-app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register file extension in window registry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720710/register-file-extension-in-window-registry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own files with custom extensions by saving the file with that particular extension. Then what you need is to associate the extension with your application.  For this you need to create the instance of FileAssociationInfo .

Check this out [System-File-Association](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17023/System-File-Association)

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for thanks! I saw a few things about messing with the registry manually but that isn't something I like doing